# Call PHP File via BATCH (Cronjob)

Tags: php, batch-file, cmd

I have a PHP file on my server which should get executed to import a CSV File. How can I do that via BATCH, just like a Cron Job does.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "BATCH"?  Why doesn't cron work in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly add php file to crontab, for this file must have 755 permission.
To add

```
php -f absolute file path
```

or you can create .sh file and call php file from it, for this also .sh file must have 755 permission.

```
#!/bin/bash
php -f absolute file path
```